# How can a templated "ResourceCache" load/create resources of type T, if they require different creation parameters/methods?

Tags: c++, templates, resources, polymorphism, containers

I just dont know how to do it..

Basically, if each template specialization type (T) have different parameters for its initialization, how can a generalized ResourceCache load/create a resource?

```
template< class T>
class ResourceCache{

  T* cache[100];

  T* LoadResource(different parameters for different  T  ){//used in a cache miss..

          Create( different parameters for different  T );

  }
}
```

If I use abstraction for, i.e., a IResourceParams class, my ResourceCache will not be able to use its own known type resource data without using polymorphism, its kinda stupid, since at runtime he knows what the type is, id be tottaly doing shit at runtime in prol of a compile time facility...I guess..

On my current try I created a templated IResourceDesc  that have a virtual T* Create() method, so you need to derive for add data and specialize the Create method, but it sucks, because I cant have a collection of IResourceDesc in the ResourceCache class ( for  comparing current loaded ones, acquiring cached resources by desc, etc)...

Answer (score 2):

In C++11, this is rather easy with a variadic template and perfect-forwarding:

```
#include <utility>

template<class... Args>
T* LoadResource(Args&&... args){
  unsigned dest_index = /* pick it */ 0;
  cache[dest_index] = new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  return cache[dest_index];
}
```

For C++03, either provide ~10 overloads with different number of parameters or go for the [in-place factory style](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/in_place_factories.html):

```
template< class T>
class ResourceCache{
  T* cache[100];

  template<class Factory>
  T* LoadResource(Factory const& f){
    unsigned dest_index = /* pick cache slot */ 0;
    void* dest = operator new(sizeof(T));
    cache[dest_index] = f.construct(dest);
    return cache[dest_index];
  }
}

template<class T, class A1>
struct in_place_factory1{
  in_place_factory1(A1 const& a1) : _arg1(a1) {}
  int* construct(void* dest) const{
    return new (dest) T(_arg1);
  }
private:
  A1 const& _arg1; // make sure the original argument outlives the factory
};

// in code
ResourceCache<int> cache;
int arg = 5;
int* res = cache.LoadResource(in_place_factory1<int,int>(arg));
```

In-place factories are basically an inferior version of perfect-forwarding variadic template functions that can *emplace* the object directly into the containers storage without requiring an already complete object for a copy.

Comment: Wow! A bunch of new knowledge! Thanks a lot. Before gasp into the c++03 solution (it will take some time), can anyone update me about c++11? Is it already being "widely" used? I mean, you already answered with c++11 version, while I only superficially know about some changes, and dont know even if theres any IDE supporting it stably(I use vs2010 ultimate)..kinda scary..How are you "practicing" c++11?

Comment: @Icebone1000: It's not the IDE that's important, but the compiler. Currently supporting variadic templates are GCC 4.5+ and Clang 3.0+ I think, and both support perfect-forwarding. VS2010 also supports perfect forwarding, but no variadic templates. There are many things in C++11 that are widely supported and used, like `auto` for type inference aswell as move semantics and lambdas. Best read up on it.

Comment: thinking about the "~10 overloads", are unused overloaded fuctions optimized out? I cant find solid info on this, looks like the only removed functions are static ones..What about templated overloaded functions? Any insight on that?

Comment: @Icebone1000: Templates are "patterns", they don't exist as real code unless instantiated. Only then will the compiler generate code for the function. In any case, there's no reason to worry about code size, really.

Comment: I think I wasnt clear, I know templates exist only when used, but what about normal function overloads that are never used? and what about overloaded functions inside templated classes (probably no difference I guess, just curious, are compilers able to optimize they out?)

Comment: After reading about in-place factories, I dont think it can save me, or I didnt realize how to. The resources Im trying to create dont know how to create themselves, they are created by another object, being explicit, they are created by a ID3D11Device*, the resources in question are ID3D11Texture2D, ID3D11InputLayouts, etc.., each require a different call on the ID3D11Device, I guess the only way is creating a wrapper for each of those, with a constructor that receives the device as param...Im starting to question myself if Im better giving up the templated way and doing a cache for each one.